# Expected value of $x^TR_x^{-1}x$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-theory

Assume that the inverse of the correlation matrix of the n dimensional column vector $x$ exists and equals $R_x^{-1}$, show that $E\{x^TR_x^{-1}x\}=n$.

Comment: I am preparing for an exam, any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $E(x_i x_j) = R_{ij}$.  Now write down your expression using indices: $E(\sum_{ij} R^{-1}_{ij} x_i x_j)$, remembering that you can interchange the expectation and the sum, and realize that what you end up with is the sum of the diagonal entries of the identity matrix.